# Defining an element in Selenium 2 and it's not being clicked on

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I've got the folling HTML on a page I'm trying to test:

```
<div class="iconlist">
                    <p>
                        <a href="/login"><img src="http://blahblahblah/icon-facebook.png" alt=""
                                                     width="26"
                                                     height="26"/></a>
                        <a href="/login"><img src="http://blahblahblah/icon-twitter.png" alt=""
                                                     width="26"
                                                     height="26"/></a>
                        <a href="/login"><img src="http://blahblahblah/icon-yahoo.png" alt=""
                                                     width="26"
                                                     height="26"/></a>
                        <a href="/login"><img src="http://blahblahblah/icon-gmail.png" alt=""
                                                     width="26"
                                                     height="26"/></a>
                    </p>
                </div>
```

I'm trying to click on each icon to verify it takes me to the login page.

I've tried the following code but it seems to just ignore it and it stays on the page.

```
WebElement logoFacebook = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[src*='icon-facebook']")).click();
```

Any ideas as to why the click() doesn't click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might the problem be that you are expecting click() to return something?

Have you tried 'driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[src*='icon-facebook']")).click();' by itself?

Comment: Worked a charm. Don't know why I didn't try just the '.click();' or split it out like 'WebElement logoFacebook = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[src*='icon-facebook']"));' .. logoFacebook.click(); .. Both work equally as well. Must have been having a bad day!